# VS Code keeps overwriting eslint setting

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

VS Code keeps overwriting the workspace setting of eslint to explicit from true

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit"
},
```

How can I prevent it from doing this? I have tried to add this into my User settings but then VS code overwrites my user settings to explicit. I cannot find a way to keep it as true for the workspace.

About VS Code:
Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: that's... weird. AFAIK, this shouldn't happen. if anything, it should be the other way around with the value update API following https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83#_code-actions-on-save-and-auto-save.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) does this happen with any code action that you put in there? or only with this particular one? 3) Does this repro in a new temporary profile with only the eslint extension enabled?

Comment: This happens when I start my VS code for this particular workspace. I can discard my changes and then it does not happen again unless I restart my VS code.